# Fill randomly shaped area of single colour by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I'm trying to fill a random area enclosed by other areas of a different color.
I'm currently using [4-pixel connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity#4-connected) to achieve this. It works, however, the filling takes way to long (Firefox askes me multiple times to stop the script. Chrome often just terminates it because the maximum call stack is exceeded). My question: How can I optimize my code or what other algorithms should I use?

PS: I fixed the mistake Wan Chap mentioned.

EDIT: I now added a global variable `canImageData` and changed the `getRGBStringFromPixel()` function. The filling works much faster now but I'm constantly getting exceeded call stack errors now leading to bigger areas only being filled partially. Does anybody have an example of a javascript fit version of the aforementioned algorithm?

EDIT FINAL: I found a different much more performant solution digging through another site's js source. I posted the solution as an answer below.

My code:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var canImageData = null;
var RGB_STRING_WHITE = '255-255-255-255';

function colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour){
 try {
  var currentPixelRGBString = getRGBStringFromPixel(x, y);
  if(currentPixelRGBString == RGBString_fill_colour || currentPixelRGBString != RGBString_region_colour)
   return;

  setPixelFromRGBString(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour);

  if(x < can.width)
   colour_fill_4_connectivity(x + 1, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if(x > 0)
   colour_fill_4_connectivity(x - 1, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if(y < can.height)
   colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y + 1, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if(y > 0)
   colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y - 1, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
 } catch(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: colour_fill_4_connectivity(' + x + ', ' + y + ', ' + RGBString_fill_colour + ', ' + RGBString_region_colour + ') -> ' + e);
 }
}

function fillColor(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour) {
 colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
}

function RGBStringToArray(valRGB) {
 return valRGB.split('-');
}

function getRGBStringFromPixel(x, y) {
 var data = canImageData.data;
 var startIndex = (x + y * can.width) * 4;
 return data[startIndex] + '-' + data[startIndex + 1] + '-' + data[startIndex + 2] + '-' + data[startIndex + 3];
}

function setPixelFromRGBString(x, y, valRGB) {
 var imageData = ctx.createImageData(1, 1);
 var data = imageData.data;
 var rgbArr = RGBStringToArray(valRGB);
 var startIndex = (x + y * can.width) * 4;
 data[0] = rgbArr[0];
 data[1] = rgbArr[1];
 data[2] = rgbArr[2];
 data[3] = rgbArr[3];
 ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, y);

 canImageData.data[startIndex] = rgbArr[0];
 canImageData.data[startIndex + 1] = rgbArr[1];
 canImageData.data[startIndex + 2] = rgbArr[2];
 canImageData.data[startIndex + 3] = rgbArr[3];
}

// TEST

function _test_getRGBStringFromPixel() {
 var res = [];
 for(var y = 0; y < can.height; y++) {
  for(var x = 0; x < can.width; x++) {
   res.push({x:x, y:y, color:getRGBStringFromPixel(x, y)});
  }
 }
 return JSON.stringify(res);
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = (function(e) {
 can.width = this.width;
 can.height = this.height;
 ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
 canImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
}).bind(img);
img.src = 'test-image.png';

can.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 var clickX = e.clientX, clickY = e.clientY;
 if(e.button === 0 && clickX <= can.width && clickY <= can.height)
  fillColor(clickX, clickY, RGB_STRING_WHITE, getRGBStringFromPixel(clickX, clickY));
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Might not be enough but get the ImageData only once and do all the update and iteration over this only ImageData's data. getImageData is really slow.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you. I'll try and update the post after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I decided to dig into the source of http://skribbl.io which has a reliable and fast filling tool. They found an iterative solution. I extracted a snippet from the source file and changed parts to make it easier to read:

```js
function DrawingBoard(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
}

DrawingBoard.prototype.getPixel = function(imageData, x, y) {
    var startIndex = 4 * (y * imageData.width + x);
    return startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < imageData.data.length ? [imageData.data[startIndex], imageData.data[startIndex + 1], imageData.data[startIndex + 2]] : [0, 0, 0]
}

DrawingBoard.prototype.setPixel = function(imageData, startIndex, r, g, b) {
    startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < imageData.data.length && (imageData.data[startIndex] = r, imageData.data[startIndex + 1] = g, imageData.data[startIndex + 2] = b, imageData.data[startIndex + 3] = 255)
}

DrawingBoard.prototype.floodFill = function(startX, startY, r, g, b) {
    var imageData = this.canvasCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), points = [[startX, startY]], targetPixelRGB = this.getPixel(imageData, startX, startY);
    if (r != targetPixelRGB[0] || g != targetPixelRGB[1] || b != targetPixelRGB[2]) {
        for (
            var c = function(t) {
                var e = imageData.data[t],
                    i = imageData.data[t + 1],
                    c = imageData.data[t + 2];
                if (e == r && i == g && c == b) return false;
                var u = Math.abs(e - targetPixelRGB[0]),
                    h = Math.abs(i - targetPixelRGB[1]),
                    l = Math.abs(c - targetPixelRGB[2]);
                return u < 1 && h < 1 && l < 1
            },
            imageHeight = imageData.height, imageHeightWidth = imageData.width; points.length;
        ) {
            var point, pointX, pointY, index, y, m;
            for (point = points.pop(), pointX = point[0], pointY = point[1], index = 4 * (pointY * imageHeightWidth + pointX); pointY-- >= 0 && c(index);) {
                index -= 4 * imageHeightWidth;
            }
            for (index += 4 * imageHeightWidth, ++pointY, y = 0, m = 0; pointY++ < imageHeight - 1 && c(index);) {
                this.setPixel(imageData, index, r, g, b);
                pointX > 0;
                c(index - 4) ? y || (points.push([pointX - 1, pointY]), y = 1) : y && (y = 0);
                pointX < imageHeightWidth - 1;
                c(index + 4) ? m || (points.push([pointX + 1, pointY]), m = 1) : m && (m = 0);
                index += 4 * imageHeightWidth;
            }
        }
        this.canvasCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
    }
}

// TEST

var db = new DrawingBoard(document.getElementById('can'));
var img = new Image();
var fillColor = [255, 0, 255];
img.onload = (function() {
    db.canvasCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}).bind(img);
img.src = 'test.png';

addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var cx = e.clientX, cy = e.clientY;

    if(
        e.button === 0 &&
        cx > 0 && cx < db.canvas.width &&
        cy > 0 && cy < db.canvas.height
    ) {
        db.floodFill(cx, cy, fillColor[0], fillColor[1], fillColor[2]);
    }
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Working fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0kuwa5e/

Answer (score 0):

It seems it just a minor mistake, in function `setPixelFromRGBString`:
Change `data[1] = rgbArr[2];` to `data[2] = rgbArr[2];`

```js
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var RGB_STRING_WHITE = '255-255-255-255';

function colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour) {
  //try {
  var currentPixelRGBString = getRGBStringFromPixel(x, y);
  if (currentPixelRGBString == RGBString_fill_colour || currentPixelRGBString != RGBString_region_colour)
    return;

  setPixelFromRGBString(x, y, RGBString_fill_colour);

  if (x > 0)
    colour_fill_4_connectivity(x - 1, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if (x < can.width)
    colour_fill_4_connectivity(x + 1, y, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if (y > 0)
    colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y - 1, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  if (y < can.height)
    colour_fill_4_connectivity(x, y + 1, RGBString_fill_colour, RGBString_region_colour);
  //} catch(e) {
  //console.log('ERROR: colour_fill_4_connectivity(' + x + ', ' + y + ', ' + RGBString_fill_colour + ', ' + RGBString_region_colour + ') -> ' + e);
  //}
}

function RGBStringToArray(valRGB) {
  return valRGB.split('-');
}

function getRGBStringFromPixel(x, y) {
  var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, x + 1, y + 1).data;
  return data[0] + '-' + data[1] + '-' + data[2] + '-' + data[3];
}

function setPixelFromRGBString(x, y, valRGB) {
  var imageData = ctx.createImageData(1, 1);
  var data = imageData.data;
  var rgbArr = RGBStringToArray(valRGB);
  data[0] = rgbArr[0];
  data[1] = rgbArr[1];
  data[1] = rgbArr[2];
  data[3] = rgbArr[3];
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
}

// TEST

var img = new Image();
img.onload = (function(e) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}).bind(img);
img.src = 'https://static1.squarespace.com/static/593357e715d5dbea570d2118/593ee768893fc0375f9c6fd5/5c7499a7e79c707a50772134/1551194769831/Test+pattern.png?format=1000w';

can.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var clickX = e.clientX,
    clickY = e.clientY;
  if (e.button === 0 && clickX <= can.width && clickY <= can.height)
    colour_fill_4_connectivity(clickX, clickY, RGB_STRING_WHITE, getRGBStringFromPixel(clickX, clickY));
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you. This fixed another problem of filling with the wrong color. The performance is not affected though. I edited the post.

Comment: Maybe try to get the whole image data and then save it to an array. Apply the action to the array instead of the imageData. Create image data for each pixel seems too much unnecessary workload.

Comment: Thanks. Kaiido's comment already suggested that. I'm currently editing my local test code to check.